# Selected option not shown (angular, html)

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-template-form

I have the following angular template form :

```
<label for="operationType" class="form-control">Operation</label>
            <select name="operationType" [(ngModel)]="operationType" (change)="setOperationType()">
                <option *ngFor="let operation of operationsList" value={{operation.value}} >{{operation.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

The problem is that the selected option is not show on my page.

I try different browser, the selected option is shown in safari but not in chrome et firefox. I don't know if it is a problem of browser.

Can you help?

Comment: Are you binding the selected value to the "operationType" in the typescript file?

Comment: yes but I have the same problem with other parts of my form without binding

Comment: In my typescript I have : operationType = '';

Comment: You need to assign a value to operationType in the ts file in order to set a default value. The value you assign should be one of the option value from the dropdown.

Comment: By doing this, the default value is correctly assigned but the value still does not display.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my css :

```
select {
    width: 100%;
    height : 20px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;;
    margin: 8px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;

  }
```

The padding was too high so I couldn't see the text.